# Module overriding in Joomla 1.6

Tags: templates, module, joomla, overriding

I am new to Joomla, started learning it just a day ago and didn't manage to find an answer to my question in the docs (which suck real bad compared to Drupal).

So what I want to do is override the whole module in a template. The documentation only suggests I can override the markup of a module by placing corresponding files in the html folder, but I have to make some corrections to the actual logic. Is copying the module, changing and then installing it as a separate entity the only way to go? I mean it makes sense that "template" folder is for "views" but with the kind of application I have to develop it is gonna be annoying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other way to consider is to replicate or fix the logic in the template. While this is not a very slick way of doing it, it is faster, especially than duplicating a whole component.

Note that you can also add your own libraries to the Joomla libraries folder to centralize your own code.

Further, if you manage your code with (for example) svn, you should not have any problems on upgrades with creating new views that may include their own logic.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can only override views.

If you want to override logic, you have 2 options:

- Change the actual logic in-place, which leads to problems on updating etc
- Duplicate the module and change the logic, as you suggested